# Difficulty with conditional or statement

Tags: javascript

I am iterating through an `HTMLCollection` looking for `innerText` if there is `innerText` I will know that there is an error on the page.  However, in some instances `innerText === undefined` and other times `innerText === ""` so I have an or statement in my if block.

My thought is this should be simple:

```
if(err_field[field].innerText !== undefined || err_field[field].innerText !== ""){
      no_error = false;
    }
```

This doesn't work, I can log out the `innerText` of each field and clearly see that they are all either `undefined` or `""`.

So after messing with variations of that for half an hour I switched tactics:

```
    if (err_field[field].innerText === undefined || err_field[field].innerText === "") {
    }else {
      no_error = false;
    }
```

This works. Why? As far as I an tell it's just an inverse of the above including some more overhead an unnecessary `else` statement.  Am I missing something?  I've tried several variations including `if (err_field[field].innerText || ...)` and  `if (err_field[field].innerText != null || ...)` nothing has worked except the example above.

Comment: `if(!err_field[field].innerText)` would be enough. Ever heard of [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values?

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I didn't realize that `""` was falsy.  If you post this as an answer I will accept because it is so succinct otherwise I'll accept the current answer as that is corect.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first block you posted, but instead of OR use AND condition, only that way you can make sure that current element does not have `innerText`.